# Rails & Github Actions - Credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, continuous-integration, github-actions, credentials

I have a Rails 6 app using the credentials storage built into Rails and I am running testing and CI on this app with Github Actions.

I have initializer code that uses credentials that passes test on my local machine because it uses credentials from `config/credentials/test.yml.enc`, however Actions can't access this file. I have seen suggestions online to set `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` as an environment variable with the key value from the credential key file, but I have set up `RAILS_TEST_KEY` (and `RAILS_MASTER_KEY`) to be the value of `config/credentials/test.key` with no luck. Does Rails know to look for this environment variable if the key file isn't present, or do I need to do something to point it to this variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apologies, if i didn’t understand your question correctly. You can reference CI ENV variables using repository secrets. For example if you have ENV variable called `RAILS_TEST_KEY` in your CI yml file.

```
env:
 RAILS_TEST_KEY: ${{ secrets.RAILS_TEST_KEY }}
```

`secrets.RAILS_TEST_KEY` value can be set in repository secrets.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets

Comment: Yup, this was my missing step, thank you! It also seems that `RAILS_TEST_KEY` doesn't work, so setting `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` in the config `env` block was correct!